# rails: complex view with three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a suggestion how I could solve the following situation:

I have an employee, who `has many` skills `through` employeeskillsets.
Every skill `belongs to` one category.
Categories are self referenced, so the following structure is possible (classified as topcategory-category-subcategory).

```
category1
|
-skill1, skill2, skill3
-category2
  |
  -category3
  -category4
   |
   -skill4, skill5
  -category5
-category6
category7
|
-skill6, skill7
```

In short, the models are related like this `employee-skill-category`
In my view I would like to list the skills for each employee with the related category to each skill.

Has anybody an idea how I could solve this? 
In addition, only those categories, where the employee has skills in, should be displayed.

If more infos are needed, I would edit those surely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the db in your controller

```
@employees = Employee.includes(skills: :category)
```

In your view, you just need to loop over them and display the values e.g. giving you the loop structure, you need to manipulate it based on your view and attributes..

```
@employees.each do |employee|
  employee.name
  employee.skills.each do |skill|
    skill.name
    skill.category.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Somehow I need to go through each category and list every skill/category inside that origin category. But as I understand, I can use `each` only on collections and in this case, I select category as singular. I feel like my brain is twisted ...